# PUZZLING -- Area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, area51

Is it OK here to put information about a proposed topic for stackexchange location ... "puzzling" ... Since puzzles may be off-topic here, check out that proposed location:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16410/puzzling

Comment: I think that choice of name is puzzling. :-P

Comment: For the benefit of anyone seeing this old question -- the puzzling site never reached critical mass and the proposal is now closed.

Comment: Since the proposal is closed, to prevent the community bot from bumping this question back up, I'm closing it as "too localized" (have to choose an arbitrary answer).

Comment: For the benefit of anyone seeing this old question -- [the puzzling site is alive and well](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).